# Can heat generate noise?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have a very basic understanding of heat and noise, but I was wondering if the oscillations of particles when hot can generate noise at extreme temperatures. It sounds crazy, but you never know.

Comment: Something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise# ?

Comment: Google "Flame speaker"